# df.loc is giving key error in linux environment where the same code is working fine in mac?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
    key         epic    uname        port   
0   PORT-100    None    user5        None   
1   PORT-101    None    user1        None   
2   PORT-102    None    NA           None   
3   PORT-103    None    NA           None   
4   PORT-104    None    user2        None   
5   PORT-105    None    user3        None
```

and I have a dictionary

```
{'PORT-10': ['PORT-100', 'ST-111'],
 'PORT-100': ['PORT-105', ],
 'PORT-101': ['PORT-103']}
```

I want to change the port column of dataframe according to the port dictionary i.e if a any key in df matches to the list of values inside the dictionary then I'll assign that dict key to df['port'] 
I am doing like below

```
for port in port_dict:
    df.loc[df['key'].isin(port_dict[port]),'port']=port
```

and it is working fine in my mac but giving key error in linux . I have tried using try...except key error, but no luck. I am  using python 3.6 in both cases.
Any idea why it is behaving differently in linux environment even if I am using same python version?

Comment: `print(df.columns)`, please.

Comment: `MultiIndex(levels=[['epic', 'type', 'uname', 'val', 'port', 'story']],
           labels=[[3, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5]])`  @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: How are you loading your data? I want to see your code.

Comment: Thanks @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ for pointing out. Solved the issue . It is a multilevel index but i was doing it as a 1D index. but while assigning columns to df even if i am using double [[]] in mac it is working fine but in linux it is expecting single [] .any idea why ?

Comment: Which versions of pandas are you using on each machine?

Comment: I believe recent versions of pandas disallowed letting you pass nested lists to `names` when assigning column. One of your machines has an older version of pandas.

Comment: Well, I was trying to nudge you for more information because your question was incomplete.

Comment: in mac it is 0.19.2 and in linux it is 0.22.0 but both are having python 3.6.. @Alex

Comment: yeaa!! you are right . Both are having different version of pandas . Since i am using same python version , so i never thought about this . Thanks a lot @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, this may be due to different versions of pandas being used. At any rate, the more idiomatic way of doing this is to use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map). You can read more about vectorizing operations over data [in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-functions).

```
port_dict2 = {v: k for k, vs in port_dict.items() for v in vs}
df['port'] = df['key'].map(port_dict2)
```

This works on my Mac and Linux Mint VM.